# Migrating from flickr to google photos

Tags: automation, flickr, google-photos

With flickr putting the kibosh on unlimited photos with the free account I'm wondering if there is a known automated way to migrate thousands of photos from  my flickr account to google photos. I've seen some ways where albums are moved over manually but this is not tenable with hundreds of albums that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have any luck finding a working solution so I built one - https://github.com/llevar/flickr_to_google_photos_migration

Here's a guide I wrote on how to do it - https://medium.com/@llevar/how-to-migrate-your-flickr-library-to-google-photos-for-free-using-apis-and-python-2c97d3cb54a2

Answer (score 0):

I just made a Node.js script to migrate all your Flickr photo sets to Google albums!

It’s still a bit raw, but if you know about command line, it’s here:
https://github.com/antoinerousseau/flickr2google

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

With Cloudsfer migration tool, you can backup photos and videos to Google Photos from various on premise systems and from any cloud storage (e.g Flickr to Google Photos).
*** You can schedule an automatic backup on a daily, monthly or weekly basis! ***
Watch this demo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ5tWEIqXTg
Learn more:
https://www.cloudsfer.com/supported-systems/google-photos/

Comment: What's your affiliation with Cloudsfer? This reads like marketing copy.